# Is it possible on latest browsers to use CSS sprite technique on scalable background images?

Tags: css, background-image, sprite, css-sprites

I feel like I'm still learning the basics of CSS as I'm struggling to implement what seems like simple, common interface requirements.  For example, I recently learned how to use CSS3 properties that allow a background image to scale to the dimensions of it's container:
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/
http://kimili.com/journal/the-flexible-scalable-background-image-redux

Plus, I've learned of the benefits of CSS sprites:
http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

So, I simply want the benefits of both, a scalable interface and minimal http requests.  As things are, when I attempt to use positioned image sprites with the appropriate background image settings, the entire image file is rendered in the container.  Is it possible to combine these two techniques or is this a worthless endevour?

Comment: Scalable background images and sprites don't really mix, at least not in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Use foreground images with a [div wrapper with alternating relative/fixed states](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/css3-zoom.html) or [:before/:after](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/oneBox.html) pseudo images to achieve this affect.